# How can we use SqlServer 2008 as sensor server to transfer my sensor data from my mobile?

Tags: database-design, android-sensors

Can we use MS SqlServer as SensorServer?

How can we use MS SqlServer 2008 as SensorServer to transfer my sensor data from my android mobile e.g temperature, image etc.  to it.

What are the other options to move my sensor data to the SensorServer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web service and connect your Android to that web service, then just send the data and save it in the SQL Server database.